# Выдвигающаяся боковая корзина на битрикс

Tags: php, ajax, битрикс

Возможно ли реализовать выдвигающуюся корзину похожую на эту?
[image: Вид корзины]

Понимаю, что можно использовать ajax, примерно накидал обработчик:

```
  BX.addCustomEvent('OnBasketRefresh',function(result){
var options = {
     url: '<?=$templateFolder?>/ajax/add2basket.php',
     type: "POST",
     target: '<?=$cartId?>',
     processData: false,
     success:
     function(res) {
          console.log('result: ', res);
           $.jGrowl("Товар добавлен в заказ");
      }
     };
$(".add_form").ajaxForm(options);
```

})

Вот сам код шаблона данной корзины

```
 <? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] AS $arItem): ?>
<?
$PR = $arItem['PR'];
$basket = $arResult['DATA']['items'][$arItem['ID']];
?>
<? endforeach;?>
<div class="basket-list d-flex w-100 flex-column align-items-start justify-content-start">
  <div class="d-flex w-100 flex-row justify-content-start mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-4 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center ">
      <h4 class="form-title  text-start mt-2 ms-2" id="basket-list">Корзина</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-2 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center">
      <button class="ms-3 btn-nav btn-nav-trash d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img class="btn-nav-trash" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/layout/images/icons/basket-refresh.png" height="20"
          width="20" />
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-6 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
      <button class="ms-3 btn-nav btn-nav-close  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <img class="btn-nav-close" src="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/layout/images/icons/close.png" height="20"
          width="20" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bue-sum mt-3 d-flex row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center"><label class="mb-0">К
        оплате:</label></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-6 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center">
      <label class="mb-0 total-price">
        <?=$arResult['DATA']['price']?>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?if(count($arResult['ITEMS']) <= 0):?>
  <span class="mt-5 ms-3">Товаров пока нет</span>
  <?else:?>
  <div data-simplebar class="table-wrapper w-100">
    <table class="basket-list  mt-4 w-100">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span>Название</span></th>
          <th class="text-center "><span>Кол-во</span></th>
          <th class="text-end"><span>Цена</span></th>
          <th class="text-end"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="basket-list-items">
        <? foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] AS $arItem):
          $PR = $arItem['PR'];
          $basket = $arResult['DATA']['items'][$arItem['ID']];
        ?>
        <tr data-basket-product-id="<?=$arItem['ID']?>">
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center basket-item">
              <img class="food-img" src="<?= $PR['PREVIEW_PICTURE'] ?>" height="50" width="90" />
              <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center ms-2">
                <span><?=$PR['NAME']?></span>
                <span class="pb-0"><?= $PR['PROPS'] ?></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <form  data-product-quantity="<?=$arItem['ID']?>" class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
              <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
                <button data-product-quantity-control="minus" data-send="form" class="basket-count-btn d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center minus-btn">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="mx-3">
                  <span data-product-quantity="placeholder" class="items-count"><?=$basket['quantity'] ?? 0?></span>
                </div>
                <button class="basket-count-btn d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center plus-btn">
                  <i class="menu-icon fa-solid fa-plus "></i>
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?=$basket['quantity'] ?? 0?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$arItem['ID']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="basketAddAction">
              </div>
            </form>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h6 data-product-price-total="<?=$arItem['ID']?>" class="text-end price mb-0"><?=$basket['price_total'] ?? 0?> р</h6>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <? endforeach;?>
        <?endif?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Суть в том, что я не понимаю, что нужно прописывать в add2basket.php, смотрел в интернете и там в основном используют модуль битрикса sale, но есть загвоздка в том что, ранее был Корпоративный сайт, и данного модуля нету (делал не я приходится плясать от того что есть)
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь источники или решение данного вопроса.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Дело в том, что этим занимаются в битриксе верстальщики, а вы лишь реализуете это. Например верстальщик через js добавляет класс open к .basket-list и в css прописывает появление корзины, а вам лишь нужно получается внедрить это. Я не знаю по каким событиям должно отрабатывать появление просто, но если задумывается, что когда добавляется товар в Корзину, она появляется, тогда вам нужно будет сделать так, что бы по событию добавления товара добавлялся класс open например, а он напоминаю уже прописан в css или js на появление корзины.

Comment: Если модуля нет - значит надо создать что-то похожее на корзину из доступного функционала. Инфоблоки должны быть - вот сделай инфоблок Корзина с нужными полями. При добавлении товара в корзину - создаешь запись в этом инфоблоке. Ну или может можно как-то проапгрейдиться чтобы модуль sale был доступен.

Comment: Сам функционал появления имеется, тут больше вопрос про отрисовку товаров в корзине. Благодарю, за ответ

Comment: Идея с инфоблоком интересная, а то уже впал в отчаяние и думал реализовать все на куках, по поводу апгрейда не знаю. Спасибо